# How i can get user email,name while end user talking to Dialog flow ChatBot on Google Hangout

Tags: dialogflow-es, chatbot, google-hangouts

Am going to integrate DialogFlow Bot with Hangout integration, I need the username and email whom my chatbot is communicating

Answer (score 0):

You will need to set a a direct API from Hangout from there you can use Data.User to grab what you need

You can see more here
https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/chat/v1/csharp/latest/classGoogle_1_1Apis_1_1HangoutsChat_1_1v1_1_1Data_1_1Message.html

Answer (score 0):

I have the same requirement but I don't really understand the answer provided here.
In Dialogflow I use the native Hangout Chat integration : https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/integrations/hangouts

So I suspect that this integration does not send all payload from Hangouts chat to Dialogflow.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this:
https://developers.google.com/hangouts/chat/reference/message-formats/events

When user sends a message, or adds the bot or does any event, you can get the name and email. For example in Python it would look like this:

```
@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def on_event():
    event = request.get_json()

    if event['type'] == 'MESSAGE':
        response = event['user']['displayName'])
        email = event['user']['email'])
```