# get username when user speaks to a dialogflow bot in Hangouts chat

Tags: dialogflow-es, google-hangouts

I am building several bots with DialogFlow and Hangouts Chat integration.
How can I retrieve the user email of the user spraking to the bot ?
When I see the request sent from Hangouts chat to Dialogflow I cannot see any information about the user, it's like an anonymous request. 
Has anybody find a workaround for that ?

Comment: Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58430351/how-i-can-get-user-email-name-while-end-user-talking-to-dialog-flow-chatbot-on-g).

Answer (score 1):

It can be retrieved using events:

For each event like a message, a new user added or removed to the chat you can call `event.user` and it has the following fields:

`event.user.name`: The user name

`event.user.email`: The user email

`event.user.displayName`: The 'display' user name

`event.user.avatarUrl`: The user avatar's img url

For example, a working code using onMessage(event) function, for each interaction with the bot, the bot will answer with the user name and the message:

```js
function onMessage(event) {

  if (event.type == "MESSAGE" || event.space.type == "DM" ) {

    var message = event.user.displayName + " said " + event.message.argumentText;

  return { "text": message };

  }
}
```

*Response:*

`Benoit said How to get usernames on Hangouts bots?`

---

**A diagram of the JSON event format on Hangouts:**

[image: Hangouts event formats JSON]

[More documentation on hangouts events format and examples of use](https://developers.google.com/hangouts/chat/reference/message-formats/events)

Comment: Thanks for this info, this is clear about the json pushed from Hangouts. My question is how I can get this info in my DialogFlow as I use Hangouts Chat integration (https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/integrations/hangouts). When message reached Dialogflow I could not see this full json in my logs

Answer (score 1):

Ok. Figured it out...

Indeed, you'll need to handle the intent using a Fullfilment.
In the default fullfilment function, you'll see this bit of code:

```
exports.dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {

const agent = new WebhookClient({ request, response });
  console.log('Dialogflow Request headers: ' + JSON.stringify(request.headers));
  console.log('Dialogflow Request body: ' + JSON.stringify(request.body));



//... REST OF THE CODE WHERE YOU 'LL HANDLE THE INTENTS

});
```

The event info that you normally get out of an apps script chat bot is in the

```
request.body
```

For example email:

```
const email = request.body.originalDetectIntentRequest.payload.data.event.user.email;
```

In that user object, you'll also find:

- email
- avatarUrl
- displayName

Answer (score 0):

Ok, solution here is to enable fulfilment and process this as a cloud function. The input json of the cloud function contains all the event json.

I wanted to reply back "Hello @name" without using cloud function